# Mediasoup error when running ObserveRTC example: `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host.docker.internal`

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mediasoup

This is the project I want to setup:
https://github.com/ObserveRTC/full-stack-examples

I started the app using this command:

```
SFU_ANNOUNCED_IP="192.168.60.79" docker-compose up
```

And this error happened at MediaSoup:

```
ObserveRTC::RestTransport Wed, 14 Dec 2022 07:44:56 GMT Request failed. canRetry: true Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host.docker.internal
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'host.docker.internal'
}
```

I found this IP from `ifconfig`:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.60.79  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.60.255
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`host.docker.internal` parameter in Docker Compose file only defined in Windows and Mac which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host

But **my OS was Linux!**

In linux Use `localhost` in host mode or `172.18.0.1` for bridge mode.

Comment: while i using ec2 instance i need to use public ip of the ec2 instance which resolves the problem for ubuntu lts but for macos i need to use host.docker.internal inside the docker to access local db

Comment: I hope you win something! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I encounter same issue in my project, and fix this issue by adding extra host configuration in docker compose

```
service:
   container_name: myService
   extra_hosts:
     - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" <---- add this part
```

My environment:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Docker 24.0.2